# How can I close BlueJeans on Microsoft Windows?

Tags: windows, bluejeans

I use [BlueJeans](https://www.bluejeans.com/) for videoconference on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate. When I close the BlueJeans window, I still an icon in the notification area. Clicking on the BlueJeans icon doesn't give any option to close it:

[image]

I tried to kill the 2 `BlueJeans.Detector.exe` processes that I see running in the Windows Desk Manager, but to no avail (they immediately restart):

[image]

How can I close BlueJeans on Microsoft Windows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it looks like the first `BlueJeans.Detector.exe` process makes sure that the second `BlueJeans.Detector.exe` is running, and vice versa, you need to kill them at the same time.

You can do so with the command:

```
taskkill /f /im BlueJeans.Detector.exe
```

To run it: 
 <kbd>WIN</kbd> +  <kbd>R</kbd> , then:

[image]